# How to multi insert rows in cassandra

Tags: insert, cassandra, batch-insert

What is the most efficient way of inserting multiple rows in cassandra column family. Is it possible to do this in a single call.

Right now my approach is to addinsert multiple column and then execute. There in a single call I am persisting one row. I am looking for strategy so that I can do a batch insert.

Comment: Which driver are you using?  Are you using CQL?  Which Cassandra version?

Comment: Cassandra version is1.2.x and I am using hector apis.

Answer (score 36):

CQL contains a `BEGIN BATCH...APPLY BATCH` statement that allows you to group multiple inserts so that a developer can create and execute a series of requests
(see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0).

The following worked for me (Scala):

```scala
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare(
"BEGIN BATCH" +    
"INSERT INTO messages (user_id, msg_id, title, body) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);" +    
"INSERT INTO messages (user_id, msg_id, title, body) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);" +    
"INSERT INTO messages (user_id, msg_id, title, body) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);" +    
"APPLY BATCH" ); 

session.execute(ps.bind(uid, mid1, title1, body1, uid, mid2, title2, body2, uid, mid3, title3, body3));
```

If you don't know in advance which statements you want to execute, you can use the following syntax (Scala):

```scala
var statement: PreparedStatement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO people (name,age) VALUES (?,?)")
var boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement)
val batchStmt = new BatchStatement()
batchStmt.add(boundStatement.bind("User A", "10"))
batchStmt.add(boundStatement.bind("User B", "12"))
session.execute(batchStmt)
```

**Note:** `BatchStatement` can only hold up to 65536 statements. I learned that the hard way. :-)

Comment: @user853509 A "great answer" that helped you, and not even an upvote?  Harsh.

Comment: Good answer.  Plus one from me.

Comment: how much insert statements can i send at one time?

Comment: In the Scala example, all `var`s should be `val`s. Object references don't change.

Comment: The latter version did not work for me. Had to replace each `boundStatement.bind(...)` with `new BoundStatement(statement).bind(...)`

Comment: I tested both approaches. First one is about 4 times faster on INSERTS for me despite the fact that I binded 1500 arguments.

Comment: The current version of the java driver does not work the way you describe here.  batchStmt.add returns a new instance.  If you keep adding to the same batchStmt, you will have an empty batch at the end of it.  This is the crummy "Fluent" programming model which I think is horrible.

Comment: Note: batch inserts are for atomic-insertions and not for performance. This could likely degrade performance compared with sending queries separately, especially when the modifications span multiple partitions: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html

Answer (score 6):

PreparedStatement and binding values might be a better option. Below are a couple of good articles on uses and misuses of Batch:

[Cassandra: Batch loading without the Batch keyword.](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e)

[Using and misusing batches](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html)

Answer (score 4):

There is a batch insert operation in Cassandra.  You can batch together inserts, even in different column families, to make insertion more efficient.

In Hector, you can use `HFactory.createMutator` then use the `add` methods on the returned Mutator to add operations to your batch.  When ready, call `execute()`.

If you're using CQL, then you group things into a batch by starting the batch with `BEGIN BATCH` and ending with `APPLY BATCH`.

Comment: Make sure you understand when this is a good idea and [when it isn't](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html). Batches don't typically improve performance and can even reduce it in the worst case.  If you don't need atomic writes, make sure to use an unlogged batch.

Comment: Good point. I think in thrift batches nearly always helped (because of the massive overhead of thrift). In CQL, you should use async inserts and prepared statements rather than batches. Except for the case when your inserts are all to the same partition, in which case batches are more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

you can add your multiple insert statements into a file and execute the file with 'cqlsh -f'.

You can also perform Batch insert with CQL into cassandra as described in below link:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html#cassandra/cql_reference/batch_r.html

Comment: Can you please fix Datastax URL above? It returns 404 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to insert multiple rows. Database connection RTT could be the performance bottle neck. In that case, we generally need a way to avoid waiting for one `INSERT` to finish so that we can begin our next `INSERT`.Currently there are two ways as far as I know:

- If data consistency matters, use `LOGGED BATCH`, but as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42930498/6777996) said, `BATCH` may not have a performance boost in all the situation.
- Otherwise, use a async api in the Cassandra client library, for example in python there is a `execute_async` method

Also, you can prepare the SQL statement before execute it. I haven't test the overall performance of a prepared statement vs plain insert. But I think if there are thousands `INSERT` or more you should get a performance boost.